# Passing back indexpath row to parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have two UITableview.  The first one shows 3 sections with 3 row each one, this is the default layout.  When the user press line 2 section 0, the second view is showed to select a value.  Once the value is selected, it returns to the first view, but this time, with a different layout.  Depending on the value selected, the first view can only show one, two or three sections.  I'm trying to achieve this behavior passing the indexpath from the child view to its parent and dynamically change the number of sections. I get the number of row selected in child view, but once it is passed to the parent view, the row numbers gets zero.

The code for child view is:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
          [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
          NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
          //Create parent view instance to pass back indexpath as a integer
          DiarioA *plc = [[DiarioA alloc] init];
          NSInteger i1 = row; 
          plc.rowTipo = i1;
          [plc release];
          [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
Pa
```

ret view (DiarioA.h)

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int rowTipo;
```

PArent view (Diario.m)

```
@synthesize rowTipo;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
       [self.tableView reloadData];
       //Check if rowTipo has value
       NSLog(@"RowTipo: %d",rowTipo);
  }

//Use rowTipo to dynamically adjust uitableview layout.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
      if (self.rowTipo==0) {
          return 3;
      }
      return self.rowTipo;
   }
```

Could you help me to indentify why I'm loosing the indexpath that is coming from the childview to parentview. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DiarioA *plc = [[DiarioA alloc] init];`
you are creating a new object here and setting the `plc.rowTipo = i1;` changes the value of this object not the parent object.
Either you pass your parent object to the child controller and then change its value like this.

```
// child .h file

DiarioA *plc;
@property (nonatomic, assign) DiarioA *plc;

//child .m file
@synthesize plc;

// code when you push your child controller
ChildController *controller = [[ChildController allo] initWithNibName.....];
controller.plc = self
```

and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
          [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
          NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
          plc.rowTipo = row;
          [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Inder, thanks. Now, It's working great. Do you prefer this instead of delegates? or both are equal efficently.  By the way, I'cant vote, because my points, however, your answer helped me a lot..

Comment: That's bad if you are not voting :(
Anyways.. it's same as delgates.. here we just passed an object and called is setter method same like delgates... just change your .h file variable into `id delegate;` and call setter on it `[delegate setRowTipo:row];` then it would look like delegation although both are the same.. now is it clear so that you can accept it and upvote it ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.  I need, at least, 15 points to vote, however, your answer is totally accepted and it was I looking for. Vote +2

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make protocol of your child view controller and make your parent view controller its delegate. Than just set delegate property after initialization of your child view controller and call your delegate method sending indexpath there.

Comment: Roman, thank. Is there another alternative instead of delegate methods? From my understanding I'm trying to simplify code.

Comment: @Memo What Roman suggests is really the only proper solution in this situation. It **will** simplify your code.

Comment: There are many solutions like posting notification or Inder's method. This time it is simple. but next time you may get into situation when one property setting is not enough.

Comment: Roman, thanks for your suggestion.  I will, as soon as I get more expertise.  I'm Finance guy developing in iphone and I haven't been very successfully with delegates; are complicated for me. So, step by step. Your feedback is appreciated.